# Empirical distribution of rows in 2d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, probability

Let's say I have a 2d numpy array A:

```
A = [[0.3, 0.2],
     [1.0, 0.1],
     [0.3, 0.1],
     [1.0, 0.1]]
```

What I would like is something that maps rows of A to their empirical distribution:

```
f([0.3, 0.2]) = 0.25
f([1.0, 0.1]) = 0.50
f([-12, 140]) = 0.00
```

Is there a nice way to do this?

Comment: Could you share the implementation of `f`?

Comment: The implementation of f is what I am looking for.

Comment: Do you mean this empirical distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function ?

Comment: Yes, with a caveat: I mean the empirical pdf - what they display there is the empirical cdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using numpy.allclose. You can choose a tolerance, here I put 1.e-10 :

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[0.3, 0.2],[1.0, 0.1],[0.3, 0.1], [1.0, 0.1]])

def f(x,tol=1.e-10):
  l = [np.allclose(x,row,tol) for row in A]
  return l.count(True)/float(A.shape[0])

print f(np.array([0.3,0.2]))
print f(np.array([1.0, 0.1]))
print f(np.array([-12, 140]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my hacky closure-based method:

```
def pdf_maker(A, round_place=10):
    counts = {}
    for i in range(A.shape[0]):
        key = tuple([round(a,round_place) for a in A[i]])
        try:
            counts[key] += 1.0
        except KeyError:
            counts[key] = 1.0

    pdf = {}
    for key in counts:
        pdf[key] = counts[key] / A.shape[0]

    def f_pdf(row):
        key = tuple([round(a,round_place) for a in row])
        try:
            return pdf[key]
        except KeyError:
            return 0.0

    return f_pdf
```

I'm sure there's a cleaner way to do it, though.